# List of JSF / Tobago Facets?

Tags: java, jsf, facet, tobago

Does anybody know a good link with a list of all existign JSF/Tobago facets containing explanation what the facet is good for?

Until now I know about the "layout" and "confirmation" facet but I haven't found a website showing up all the other existing facets...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the documentation for the individual tags has a description for their facets.

For example, http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html describes some of the facts it accepts, like header and footer.

If you do find a comprehensive list of all facets for every tag though, let me know. :)

Comment: For standard JSF components, it's obviously already in the tlddocs, but he's talking about Tobago which has indeed opaque documentation. Good luck finding it at their dev site :) I gave up after 15 mins.

Comment: Exactly, the tobago facets are hard to find... So therefore your link does not help :( Thanks for the idea nevertheless!

Comment: My bad. I read JSF/Tobago as Standard JSF tags and Tobago tags.